# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Error Bukkit Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

Okay so I'm working on a Bukkit plugin currently and decided to add in a feature that schedules broadcasts. To store the broadcasts I'm using the config.yml file and taking the broadcasts from there. The issue I'm having is the code keeps returning and IndexOutOfBoundsException which I haven't been able to fix yet.

Here's my code:

```
package uk.co.thek4web.broadcaster;

import java.util.List;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class bcscheduler extends BukkitRunnable {

    private Broadcaster plugin;
    public bcscheduler(Broadcaster plugin){
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
    private int bcnumber = 0;
    public void run() {
        //String list from config
        List<String> bcm = plugin.message();
        //Broadcasts the next broadcast messsage in the config
        plugin.bc(bcm.get(bcnumber));
        //Makes sure broadcasts don't repeat, goes onto the next broadcast.
        if(bcnumber < bcm.size()){
            bcnumber++;
        }
        else{
            bcnumber = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the exception I keep getting:

```
2013-08-04 20:20:43 [WARNING] [Boss Broadcast] Task #4 for Boss Broadcast v0.3 generated an exception
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:603)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:381)
    at uk.co.thek4web.broadcaster.bcscheduler.run(bcscheduler.java:16)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:53)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:345)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:522)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.DedicatedServer.t(DedicatedServer.java:226)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:486)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:419)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:582)
```

I've tried a few things but none of them have worked so any ideas on where exactly I've went wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: I think `if(bcnumber < bcm.size()){` is your problem. When it's one less than `bcm.size()` it'll still increment past the size once. So, `bcm.size() - 1` fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are going out of the list size. By the way here some advices about your code

```
 List<String> bcm = plugin.message(); 

// You must check that your list isn't empty before doing your instructions
 if((bcm != null) && !bcm.isEmpty()){
    plugin.bc(bcm.get(bcnumber));


    if(bcnumber < bcm.size()-1){
        bcnumber++;
    }
    else{
        bcnumber = 0;
    }
 }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

> if(bcnumber < bcm.size()-1)

Lets say size is 3, the indices will be 0,1,2. Consider the case when bcnumber = 2

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
public void run() {
  List<String> bcm = plugin.message();
  plugin.bc(bcm.get(bcnumber++));
  bcnumber = bcnumber % bcm.size();
}
```